# ActiveRecord find and only return selected columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

#### edit 2

If you stumble across this, check both answers as I'd now use pluck for this

---

I have a fairly large custom dataset that I'd like to return to be echoe'd out as json. One part is:

```
l=Location.find(row.id)
tmp[row.id]=l
```

but I'd like to do something like:

```
l=Location.find(row.id).select("name, website, city")
tmp[row.id]=l
```

but this doesn't seem to be working. How would I get this to work?

thx

**edit 1**
alternatively, is there a way that I can pass an array of only the attributes I want included?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

### In Rails 2

```
l = Location.find(:id => id, :select => "name, website, city", :limit => 1)
```

...or...

```
l = Location.find_by_sql(:conditions => ["SELECT name, website, city FROM locations WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1", id])
```

[This reference doc](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/find/class) gives you the entire list of options you can use with `.find`, including how to limit by number, id, or any other arbitrary column/constraint.

### In Rails 3 w/ActiveRecord Query Interface

```
l = Location.where(["id = ?", id]).select("name, website, city").first
```

Ref: [Active Record Query Interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)

You can also swap the order of these chained calls, doing `.select(...).where(...).first` - all these calls do is construct the SQL query and then send it off.

Comment: but I only want a single instance not all

Comment: I edited my answer. `:limit` should do this, or `:first` or `:last` or whatever, depending on what you want. The reference document I linked to will tell you how to do all that.

Comment: Updated to include how to do an equivalent query in Rails 3.

Answer (score 222):

**pluck(column_name)**

This method is designed to perform select by a single column as direct SQL query Returns Array with values of the specified column name The values has same data type as column.

Examples:

```
Person.pluck(:id) # SELECT people.id FROM people
Person.uniq.pluck(:role) # SELECT DISTINCT role FROM people
Person.where(:confirmed => true).limit(5).pluck(:id)
```

see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-pluck

**Its introduced rails 3.2 onwards and accepts only single column. In rails 4, it accepts multiple columns**

Comment: OK, pluck with multiple columns is awesome.. just learned that on this answer. Rails 3 though needs the accepted answer.

Comment: The accepted answer is right cause pluck wasn't available then.

Comment: **User.pluck(:email,:id)**
SELECT "users"."email", "users"."id" FROM "users"

Comment: Model.uniq is now Model.distinct (at least in Rails 5).

Comment: Seems you can do the following in rails 3.2: `Location.select([:name, :website, :city])` if you pass it an array

Answer (score 50):

My answer comes quite but this is what you can do:

```
Location.select(:name, :website, :city).find(row.id)
```

Btw, this is **Rails 4**

Comment: This should be the selected answer and most directly answers the question.

Comment: This was asked over 10 years ago. The Rails and ActiveRecord version have gone through major changes. Luckily things have definitely simplified. This is how I would do it in modern times, but it doesn't hurt to verify what version you're running on.

Comment: this is the way