# problems in using search function in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to do a simple search function. This is the function in the module. I have two columns: title and description. But I get an error. Instead of posts I need to have select "title" in there.

```
def self.search(search)
  if search
    find(:all, :conditions => ['name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
  else
    find(:all)
  end
end
```

The error I get is:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: name: SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE (name LIKE '%first%')
```

UPDATE:

Here is my index.html.erb file. I have essentially used a form and listed all the posts along with their content. How do I change the file to display only the searched item? Initially all should be listed. I am not able to understand how to do this. Any ideas?

```
<h1>Our Blog</h1>
<%= form_tag posts_path, :method => 'get' do %>
  <p>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
  </p>
<% end %>

<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <h2><%= link_to post.title,post %></h2>
  <p><%= post.content %></p>
  <hr />
  <%= link_to "Add a new post", new_post_path %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: If you say nothing to AR it will search for whole rows: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911014/activerecord-find-and-only-return-selected-columns

Answer (score 0):

You have no column `name` in your table `posts` i think you want search on `title` & `description` so try following

```
find(:all, 
     :conditions => ['title LIKE ? OR description like ?', "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%"])
```