# MySQL and solving "n+1"pattern (over 1M records)

Tags: mysql, sql, join, geolocation

I am running this query - with ActiveRecord (Ruby On Rails):

```
@hotels = Hotel.includes(:services).within(distance, origin: city).where('reception = ?', 0).order("distance ASC")
```

The radius is 100 miles and this query lasts about 40 seconds to perform. In the table `hotels` is about 300,000 records, in `services` is 1,100,000 records. The thing is - in my opinion - the "n+1" problem. I'd like to improve the search, because waiting 40-50 seconds to fetch results is not very user-friendly.

I've tried to rewrite the ActiveRecord query with raw MySQL, something like this:

```
SELECT hotels.*,
    69.0 * HAVERSINE(hotels.latitude,hotels.longitude, #{lat},#{lng}) AS distance
FROM hotels
WHERE hotels.latitude BETWEEN #{lat} - (#{distance} / 69.0)
    AND #{lat} + (#{distance} / 69.0)
    AND hotels.longitude BETWEEN #{lng} - (#{distance} / (69.0 * COS(RADIANS(#{lat}))))
    AND #{lng} + (#{distance} / (69.0 * COS(RADIANS(#{lat})))) 
    AND hotels.reception = 0
ORDER BY distance
```

When I run this query, the application is loading data even more time - 400 seconds to be exact. I think it's because the "n+1" thing - in this query, there are not involved data from the **services** table. I've tried to add this table to the query, like this:

```
SELECT hotels.*,
    69.0 * HAVERSINE(hotels.latitude,hotels.longitude, #{lat},#{lng}) AS distance
FROM hotels
JOIN hotel_services ON hotel_services.hotel_id = hotels.id
JOIN services ON hotels.id = hotel_services.service_id
WHERE hotels.latitude BETWEEN #{lat} - (#{distance} / 69.0)
    AND #{lat} + (#{distance} / 69.0)
    AND hotels.longitude BETWEEN #{lng} - (#{distance} / (69.0 * COS(RADIANS(#{lat}))))
    AND #{lng} + (#{distance} / (69.0 * COS(RADIANS(#{lat})))) 
    AND hotels.reception = 0
ORDER BY distance
```

But it seems to be the same - there's still the same **n+1** problem.

Is in MySQL a way how to handle this issue? To load everything in a single query would be probably the most efficient, but is there a way to do it?

Thank you guys.

**EDIT:**

Generated SQL from ActiveRecord (it generates 2 queries):

```
  SELECT (ACOS(least(1,COS(0.5943236044502174)*COS(-2.0637416211957023)*COS(RADIANS(hotels.latitude))*COS(RADIANS(hotels.longitude))+ COS(0.5943236044502174)*SIN(-2.0637416211957023)*COS(RADIANS(hotels.latitude))*SIN(RADIANS(hotels.longitude))+
     SIN(0.5943236044502174)*SIN(RADIANS(hotels.latitude))))*3963.1899999999996)
  AS distance,hotels.* 
  FROM `hotels` 
  WHERE (((ACOS(least(1,COS(0.5943236044502174)*COS(-2.0637416211957023)*COS(RADIANS(hotels.latitude))*COS(RADIANS(hotels.longitude))+     COS(0.5943236044502174)*SIN(-2.0637416211957023)*COS(RADIANS(hotels.latitude))*SIN(RADIANS(hotels.longitude))+
    SIN(0.5943236044502174)*SIN(RADIANS(hotels.latitude))))*3963.1899999999996)
     <= 100.0)) 
  AND (reception = 0) ORDER BY distance ASC

SELECT `hotel_services`.* FROM `hotel_services` WHERE `hotel_services`.`hotel_id` IN (237440, 237441, another IDs)
```

**EDIT2:**
*Also why do you join hotel_services and services? You don't seem to use them for anything.*

It's because of the model:

```
class Hotel < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :hotel_services, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :services, through: :hotel_services
end
```

Comment: Please post what indexes you have on those tables. Also include the SQL your ActiveRecord query generates and the results of `EXPLAIN`. (The N+1 problem is not what you think, at least it is not relevant for the second and third query you show.)

Comment: Also why do you join `hotel_services` and `services`? You don't seem to use them for anything.

Comment: @Tomalak thank you for your comment. There are no comments on the table `hotels`. I've tried to add `CREATE INDEX latitude_longitude ON hotels(latitude, longitude)`, but it didn't have any effect on the speed. I updated the OP.

Comment: @Tomalak OP updated one more time.

Comment: For starters, get rid of the `SELECT *`. Here's how: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911014/activerecord-find-and-only-return-selected-columns (never use `SELECT *` in production code, always select only what you really need). That won't increase the speed of the query very much because that calculation in the WHERE clause is what bogs it down. I'm afraid I can't advise you on that, though.

Comment: if you always filter with a distance from a city origin, you could create a "hotel_city_distances" table with cities in the hotels neighborhood. It's a bit ugly but it saves the time for distances calculus.